# Germ layer and platyhelminthes

Tags: zoology

Some introductory biology textbooks state that sometimes the body cavity is formed from pouches pinched off from the endoderm. **So, I am interested in understanding  what 'pouches pinched off' actually means?** Also, are **platyhelminthes triploblastic or diploblastic (my professor says that they are diploblastic but books write that they are triploblastic).**

Comment: Could you split this into two questions? Since the two don't seem to have a relation as platys dont have a coelom itself. I get it that they are 2 separate things you talk about but still!

Comment: @polisetty you can answer both qs: What does 'pouches pinched off' means and the other one is whether platyhelminthes are triploblastic?

Comment: planarians seem to be triploblastic. There is a reference to *three* germ layers in this paper https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jose_Martin-Duran/publication/221982471_Planarian_embryology_in_the_era_of_comparative_developmental_biology/links/00b4952ea46adccee6000000.pdf skip to the embryology part. I guess the other two classes too should turn out to be triploblastic